# GitHub: How to do code review on new file with more than 1500 lines

Tags: git, github

On a project that I work on, we have a major feature branch which is nearing a merge into the main branch.  There are a lot of commits which shouldn't reviewed individually, so I created a PR for the branch and looked at the per-file diff https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/2952/files

However, there are a few new files which exceed GitHub's diff limit of 1500 lines. I can click to view the file, but then GitHub's commenting interface is no longer available.

So the question is, how do I CR a file addition on GitHub, where the file has more than 1500 lines in it?

Comment: Hmm, just checked. The page slows down the browser a bit (FF-41), but it's still possible to add a comment for a particular line.

Comment: Likely the longest file in the review is `cabal-install/Distribution/Client/ProjectConfig.hs` which is 1402 lines long, isn't it?

Comment: Search for "not shown" and you'll see two files, BuildTarget and ProjectPlanning, which exceed 1500.

Comment: Ahha, now I see it. Well, likely it's a restriction of github, sorta artificial. Either ask them to remove it, or make your comments to the fle e.g. in the conversation tab (well, it's less convenient) or you may split the addition of the long file into two commits each of which don't exceed the limit and so on

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate that you avoid aiming for a GitHub-specific solution. Instead, You could do your code review with *traditional* tools. The most reliable one is command-line git. Fetch the remote branch to your local machine and then:

```
> git log -p -n 1 COMMIT_ID -- INTERESTING_FILE(s)
```

Ex:

```
> git log -p -n 1 abcdef -- foo.txt bar.txt
```

- `-p` to get a "patch"
- `-n 1` for single commit
- `--` to start a list of files
- `COMMIT_ID` also can be a tag name, branch name, and whatever else you like to target your commits

On many systems, you'll be able to scroll up/down using the `less` pagination tool; often out of the box.

And more handy options over in the manual pages: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

---

Alternatively, I suppose that GUI tools such as [[gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)] would be able to handle all that buffering/scrolling too. You would get the best performance when running that *locally* too. While it's possible to get that via remote-desktop and/or remote-x, there's often too much lag when it's all piped over a network connection.

Note: I don't often use gitk, so I can't be 100% certain about its ability to handle very large files. Please let me know if this is not an option, in comments.

Comment: Yes but you won't be able to write in-line comments that the other contributors reviewers can view and comment on. That would then need to be done by eMail and would be lost to newcomers.

Comment: Ah, yes. I had totally forgotten about that *magic goodness*. Well, they could always whip up a discussion around a coffee cable, make a nice blog about it, leverage G+ or OneNote or Google Docs; and in the end leave a *link* to the review artifacts in GitHub. Desperate times, desperate measures, eh?

Comment: Or I could just use a different CR tool like Phabricator which actually handles this correctly...

Comment: That's an interesting find! I wonder how Phabricator stacks up against GitLab (not GitHub, they look very similar in name).